# Help to understand the p-value definition

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm studying [all statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225) by Wasserman and on page 156 he defines p-values:

> **10.11 Deﬁnition**. Suppose that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$ we have a size $\alpha$ test with rejection region $R_{\alpha}$. Then,
>
> $$\text{p-value} = \inf\{\alpha: T(X^n)\in R _{\alpha}\}$$
>
> That is, the p-value is the smallest level at which we can reject
> $H_0$.

Suppose I have $x^i$ the realization of $X^n$, how do I calculate its p-value using this definition? I'm a little confused because the definition doesn't mention when the observed values come into play.

Comment: The answer is given in Theorem 10.12, which follows the sentence "The following result explains how to compute the $p$-value."

Comment: @symplectomorphic the problem is he doesn't prove this theorem.